# Cannot find module '@react-native-community/cli' when trying to run the android project

Tags: android, react-native

When I run `npx react-native run-android`, I got this error:

`Cannot find module '@react-native-community/cli'`

I run `npm list @react-native-community/cli` and got the following version information:

```
└─┬ react-native@0.61.5
  └── @react-native-community/cli@3.0.4
```

Anyone has a clue how I can solve the issue?

Comment: can you delete package-lock.json file and node_modules folder and  run npm install?

Comment: try to update your react-native-cli.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me in the past. Doing a clean install of the app and recloning the repository worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove node_modules folder and run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

From what it seems you need to install react-native-community, try after installing that
`npm install -g react-native-cli`

Hope it helps